# Lazily load query parameters using JAX-RS (Jersey)

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have a HTTP GET method in my JAX-RS (Jersey) service, but I would like it to accept a dynamic number of query parameters. Nevertheless, I want to use the Jenkins API to wrap this parameters in a `@BeanParam` entity, but lazily, like this:

```
@GET
public <T extends MyMessage> Response get(@PathParam("entity") String entity, @Context Request request) {
    /* Get the class that would normally be a parameter of this method, like this:
     *    [...] get(@PathParam("entity") String entity, @BeanParam MyMessage m)
     */
    Class<T> clazz = getMessageClass(entity);

    /* That's the magic part I would like to know how to do: */
    T message = createMessageFromRequest(request, clazz);

    /* ... then I would deal with my message however I wanted. */
}
```

I know I could inject `UriInfo` and read the map of queryParams "manually", but my point is to use the Jersey API to keep things organized and don't have to convert the Strings manually to the right param types.

Just as en example, my `getMessageClass(entity)` would look something like this:

```
switch(entity) {
    case 'foo':
        return FooSpecificGet.class;
    default:
        return CommonGet.class;
}
```

and the classes:

```
class CommonGet {
    @QueryParam("page")
    private int pageNumber;

    @QueryParam("pageSize")
    private int pageSize;

    ...
}

class FooSpecificGet extends CommonGet {
    @QueryParam("fooFilter")
    private String fooFilter;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Jenkins?! You mean Jersey, don't you?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, fixed

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me. I think `@DefaultValue` might be the best fit.